# Arduino RTC - getting the time from RTC after the power is cut off

Tags: arduino-uno, rtc

I have a new DS1307 (original, not a Chinese rip off), with a new battery. It is working great, but when I turn the Arduino off (it is currently connected to laptop) and then turn it back on, it resets the time.

The line that sets the time is (in setup part of code):

```
setDS1307time(30, 42, 21, 4, 26, 11, 14);
```

So, when the Arduino gets the power back it runs the program again and it overrides the correct current time.

How can I avoid this?

Comment: Remove that line of code. You only need to set the time once.

Comment: But how do I set the time for the first time? Upload the program with this line and then upload it for the second time without this line?

Comment: Make a time-setting function in your code, and in your `loop()` code watch for a specific command that sets the time. I use 'T20151201101010' in my own machines. When they get such a command, they adjust their clock. You will see that the DS1307 can grow slowly off-base, and having a time-setting function comes handy.

Comment: Alright, I'm a noob, can you please tell me more, or can you send me your source code?

Comment: How are you accepting commands for your application? Basically whatever that process is, add another command to set the time.

Comment: Yeah but set to what? I'm totally confuesed right now

Comment: Oh, you'd set it to whatever time the user (the issuer of the command) says it is. In the example above the time is 2015-12-01 10:10:10 (today at 10:10:10 in the morning, presumably local time). The string of numbers would need to be parsed into something that could be used to set the RTC.

Comment: I'm not sure if we understand each other. There will be no user, if power is cut off, arduino has to get time from either RTC or NTP as soon as possible, there is no chance of doing it manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without knowing the DS1307 well, I think there are two options:

1. Make the setting of the clock a UI function (you should probably do this in any case since you will want users to have the ability to set the clock). The user would have to initiate the action (and put in the time to set) so there would be no problems the clock getting reset inappropriately, or
2. Do a check for sanity of the clock before you run that line. You might be able to do that through the clock API (e.g., make a call to check the time, or to get the clock status and see if it makes sense) or you could do it by storing the clock status in nonvolatile memory. The very worst case would be that you store the time of last boot and check that it seems reasonable (e.g., the time you get from the RTC is after the last boot and is within reason – say no more than a month or a year ago). If the time is too far off to feel confident you could issue a "check time" warning.

If you have a network connection using NTP as well as the RTC would be a very smart option. NTP can hold the time within a few milliseconds. The RTC would then provide you with protection against a network outage.

If you are using the Arduino to manage scheduled events one thing you'll want to think about is events that are scheduled in a moment of time that is either "skipped" as you advance the clock or that "repeats" if you set the clock back. One way to handle that is to never "jump" time, but to always just speed it up or slow it down.

Comment: The point is, I just need to set the time once and then let it be for indefinite amount of time.

Comment: No. You will see that you will need to readjust the time regularly. The DS1307 isn't that precise.

Comment: But since you have a network connection, it would be good to look into running NTP. NTP (network time protocol) will hold your time to within a fraction of a second.

Comment: No matter how good the RTC is there are reasons why you might want to set the time – battery failure, summer time, moving to a different time zone, initial setting error, …).

Comment: yeah but NTP server will not help at all if my connection falls. Maybe use NTP server if the power is cut off and maybe once a week to refresh the time?

Comment: NTP expects the network to go down from time to time. It will recover as soon as it can communicate with its peers again. In the mean time the RTC will help you stay close and will give you a good estimate of the time if you need to reboot. You could use NTP to update the RTC from time to time as well.

Comment: But I need to get time from NTP server every 30 seconds or so (it could be every minute, but I was trying NTP time before and there were some faults here and there and I didn't get the correct current time. Is this OK, or will it screw up with CPU usage too much? Or should I use RTC time, and refresh it once a day (at 0:00, get NTP packet and refresh RTC time with it)

Comment: I would just let it run. You could cut it down to every few minutes or even every day depending on how good a job the Arduino is doing of keeping time. But I don't think you'll have issues of CPU utilization.

Comment: So is constant RTC time with NTP packet refresh okay? Or are you talking about constant NTP time with RTC as backup?

Comment: I would probably do the later, but I think either one is fine. The one thing I'd want to confirm is whether or not NTP can work intermittently. Some of what it does is to measure propagation delays so that it can accurately set the clock. You might need to read the NTP spec or experiment a bit if you feel like you can't run in continuously.

Comment: Exactly, I was doing a test, and in like 2/100 of NTP packet request failed. And if I set to get the time every minute, every fail could mean bad things for me. I could set it to 30 seconds, but then again, who said there can be no two fails in a row? RTC is great so far and I think it should be fine if I would refresh it once a day (and if power is cut off). Even though I'll try to get the time from RTC (if power is cut off), because what is the point of RTC if it doesn't save the time when the power is cut off?

Comment: NTP should deal just fine with request failures. It should definitely **not** set a bogus time – the Internet is designed around the idea that the network is not guaranteed to be reliable. As you are testing a good thing to do would be to compare the RTC with NTP time over a decently long interval (at least long enough for the RTC to start to drift off). I think the DS1307 is good for a few seconds a day, so you could probably get by with running NTP every couple of hours (so that time would stay close even during a relatively long outage).

Comment: Great, then I'll just use RTC as primary time source, and run NTP method  every few hours to get exact current time. Then I'll just parse that time and set RTC. Btw, what is the easiest way to find out that the power was cut off? Like if(powerIsBack(){runNTPmethod()} ? And btw, you are a great person, this is not the first question you are helping me with, and you seem very patient with  noobs :)

Answer (score 1):

If setup() runs, it is because the system has been restarted. It could becuase the reset button was pushed, or it could be due to a power-cycle. But either way, the code will start over completely. So you could

1. Deal with restart issues in setup() as it will only be called once per session (unless you call it in your own code); or
2. Make a variable `static boolean PowerCycled = true;` and clear it once your code has dealt with its re-start issues. After a restart, the initialzed data will get reloaded, including `PowerCycled` with it's initial value of `true` restored.

Comment: Yeah, I'll probably go with boolean variable and it should work just fine, thank you!